# auspicious vs auspicial - why two of them and etymology

Tags: word-choice, etymology

I always knew the word auspicious. 
A colleague of mine used the word auspicial and I thought this was a spelling mistake.

I made a search and am seeing it in a lot of dictionaries.

Does anyone know the etymology of this word?

Comment: Because we dropped [*auspicatory*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/auspicatory) somewhere along the way - unlike with *propitiate*, where we still have all three forms. (Most dictionaries list it as archaic.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Auspicial](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/auspicial)*** appears to be a [less common variant](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=auspicial%2C%20auspicious&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Causpicial%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Causpicious%3B%2Cc0) of auspicious.

origin of  auspicial:

> 1605–15; < Latin auspici(um) [auspice](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/auspice) + -[al](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-al)